# Columns types are gone after expanding table with Table.ExpandTableColumn in PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I was making a query, and once I finished it, I got lots of errors. After some exploration I figured out the cause of errors - after expanding columns from grouping (sum aggregation) all the columns types, assigned on previous steps, have gone completely. So here's example.

Let's say, I have the following table:

[image: IMG1]

PowerQuery query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    ChangedType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
                     Source,
                     {
                         {"ID", Int64.Type},
                         {"Date1", type date},
                         {"Sum", Int64.Type}
                     }),
    GroupedRows = Table.Group(
                     ChangedType,
                     {"ID"},
                     {
                         {"SUM_GROUP", each List.Sum([Sum]), type number}, 
                         {"ALL_ROWS", each _, type table}
                     }),
    ExpandedALLROWS = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
                         GroupedRows,
                         "ALL_ROWS",
                         {"ID", "Date1", "Sum"},
                         {"ALL_ROWS.ID", "ALL_ROWS.Sum", "ALL_ROWS.Date1"})
in
    ExpandedALLROWS
```

On *ChangedType* step everything is OK:

[image: IMG2]

But on *ExpandedALLROWS* step all types are gone:

[image: IMG3]

Is there a way to retain columns types? Or should I change types in the end of a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually no solution for this as of now. There's a [similar question](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Set-column-type-while-expanding-from-merged-query/td-p/307648) posted in Power BI Community. You can check it out to see how you can go about it.

There's an [idea posted](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/17678083-preserve-data-types-when-expanding-table-columns) in Power BI ideas website. You can vote it to get it implemented soon.

There also [a blogpost](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2017/09/25/setting-data-types-on-nested-tables-in-m/) that might be helpful depending on how you can customize the code to your need.